# Change TimeZoneInfo standard TimeZone that DateTime uses internally

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I want to change the TimeZone such that everywhere in my code `DateTime.Now` automatically get the time for the TimeZone I configured and `DateTime.ToLoclTime()` also converts to the configured time rather than the system time.

In TimeZoneInfo and DateTime I did not find any option to do so, is there a way to do it or do I have to put more effort into a workaround?

Comment: DateTime does not really know anything about TimeZones and you can't change the behavior of the mentioned methods you need to write your own. For example you could create an extension method that uses [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-7.0)

Comment: It does indeed do know, internally its using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime when you do DateTime.ToLocalTime() that is why I thought it should be possible. There does not seem to be a way to replace the TimeZoneInfo though :/